# Java's Generic, Inheritance and Inner static classes compilation issue

Tags: java, android-studio, generics, javac

I have weird compilation issue related to the usage of inherited static inner class as the Generic type.

*Just in case*: each of individual code snippet is a **separate** class in the **same** package.

*ParentOuter & ParentInner:*

```
public class ParentOuter <T extends ParentOuter.ParentInner> {
    T field;

    public static class ParentInner {
    }
}
```

*ChildOuter & ChildInner:*

```
import com.company.ChildOuter.ChildInner;
//import com.company.ParentOuter.ParentInner;

public class ChildOuter extends ParentOuter <ChildInner> {

    public static class ChildInner extends ParentInner {
    }
}
```

*TopLevelChild:*

```
public class TopLevelChild extends ParentOuter.ParentInner {
}
```

Following is the result of compilation:

```
$ javac *.java
ChildOuter.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    public static class ChildInner extends ParentInner {
                                           ^
  symbol:   class ParentInner
  location: class ChildOuter
ChildOuter.java:6: error: type argument ChildInner is not within bounds of type-variable T
public class ChildOuter extends ParentOuter <ChildInner> {
                                             ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends ParentInner declared in class ParentOuter
2 errors
```

Notes:

1. When I uncomment `import com.company.ParentOuter.ParentInner;` then
   compilation is successful.
2. When I use `<TopLevelChild>` instead of `<ChildInner>` in the `ChildOuter` then compilation is successful

Questions:

1. So, from what I see, looks like, `javac` is not able to determine,
   that `ChildInner` is sub-class of `ParentInner`, when it used as the
   Generic type.

   Is it really so? If so - then why? Is expected behaviour or an issue in `javac`?
2. Also *Android Studio* highlight *import* of `ParentInner` as "unused import" and **removes** it when run "Optimize imports", which makes code not compilable.

   So, again - is it issue of `Android Studio`  or `javac` ?

---

*P.S.* I was facing with similar issue for the long time, but finally decided to post this question.

Hope, it's not duplicate as its 1st time I am not able to find an answer neither in single source nor by analysing combination of answers/articles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, We can resolve this without importing "ParentInner".

The root cause is, the compiler is not able to resolve the "ParentInner". Since "ParentInner" is the static member of "ParentOuter".

So instead of importing "ParentInner" we can simply mention "ParentOuter.ParentInner"

Please find the tweaked ChildOuter.java,

```
    package com.company;

import com.company.ChildOuter.ChildInner;
//import com.company.ParentOuter.ParentInner;

public class ChildOuter extends ParentOuter <ChildInner> {

    public static class ChildInner extends ParentOuter.ParentInner {
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps. Thanks

Comment: Rajesh, thanks for `extends ParentOuter.ParentInner` fix. It indeed compiles fine and I have not issue with IDEA.

Comment: But there are **2** things, which are still _not fully clear_ to me. **1st** of all: why specifying of `ParentOuter.` is needed only if it used with _generics_? E.g. when I remove generic info from `ParentOuter ` and `ChildOuter ` I can freely write & compile `ChildInner extends ParentInner`, etc. **2nd** question is why IDEA remove `ParentOuter.ParentInner` as redundant, but code is _not compiling_ without it then? Is it bug in IDEA?